# How to get Application Context variable before the user login in seam

Tags: java, servlets, seam, servletcontextlistener

When server at startup time we  set all configuration variables to application context.

How to get context variables before the user login ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class which implements ServletContextListener interface and override contextInitialized method. Following code shows the example.
This code will be executed when the application is loaded on server and hence, before user logs into it.

```
public class ItmContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
     sce.getServletContext();
     //do the required operations               
}
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its just a string parameter u need to assign. Use `<context-param>` in your web.xml.
In case you need Objects say Connection object for database. I would prefer having the string variables like JNDI names or db name, schema name configured in web.xml so that i do not need to recompile my java code if the configuration changes any day, and add a listner as mentioned in above post to create those java objects(connection object in this example).